# MySQL inserting data from one table to a different one with matching fields

Tags: mysql, field

I am struggling to insert the records from my table1 to my table2. They have similar structure but some columns are different. For example they would be like:

```
Table1:
|A|B|C|D|E|F|

Table2:
|A|C|E|F|
```

Now what I want to do is take the data from table 1 and insert only the matching fields into table 2. Since there are 80 columns, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select column which you want to insert

```
INSERT INTO table2 (A,C,E,F)
SELECT A,C,E,F
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: So I am forced to write all 80 columns by name? There's no other way to automatically select the shared ones?

Answer (score 0):

1st select columns that you want to copy, using SELECT statement. Insert them to where you want to put them, using INSERT statement. Understand below code and create your own query.

```
INSERT into tableB (column1, column2, column3) SELECT column2, column3, column1 FROM tableA;
```

- tableB is the table where you want to insert data.
- tableA is the    table where you select/get data.
- (column1, column2, column3) is the INSERT column order for tableB.
- you should select columns from tableA compatible to above order.
- In above example tableA column2 copy to tableB column1, tableA
  column3 copy to tableB column2, tableA column1 copy to tableB column3tableB.

Comment: I understand your answer is correct. However, could you explain a little to why this is correct and could you please stick to a syntax style keywords as uppercase keywords as lowercase, not a mix of both also please use backticks when showing column names in case the OP has used a keyword as a column name? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @martin-barker, I edited my post according to what you mentioned above. Therefore Kindly upvote it as per stackoverflow guidelines if you found it is as per your expectation. Thank you!